# Show Alt Text Keyboard

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I have an EditText for an ip address or DNS entry.
Most people will use an ip address so I want to default the soft keyboard to the number pad.
I can do that with:

```
android:inputType="phone"
```

But then I can't get back to the text keyboard if they want to enter a DNS entry instead.

I would prefer to show the alternate text keyboard(?123) instead of the numberpad so the user can easily switch to the text keyboard if needed.

How do I do that?

Reference: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/creating-input-method.html

Answer (score 1):

You can programatically change the `inputType` using the [setInputType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setInputType%28int%29) function. So you could just put a button on your interface that allows the user to switch between the two types of keyboards.

Answer (score 0):

what about

```
android:inputType="number"
```

Comment: nope. "number" does that same thing as "phone" except the "." key doesn't work.